# Summing the elements of a __m256i vector

Tags: c, vector, intel, simd, avx

I am looking to sum the elements contained in a `__m256i` vector and extract the result in a int in C.

Basically, I am trying to achieve this, but using AVX:

```c
sum += key[l] + key[l + 1] + key[l + 2] + key[l + 3] + key[l + 4] + key[l + 5] + key[l + 6] + key[l + 7];
```

Using AVX512, I have found the `_mm512_reduce_add_epi32` instruction in AVX512, which does exactly what I am looking for, but I haven't been able to find the equivalent in AVX/AVX2.

I have tried the following but it doesn't appear to be correct:

```c
__m256i key_vec = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *) key + l);
__m256i result = _mm256_hadd_epi32(key_vec, key_vec);
result = _mm256_hadd_epi32(result, result);                
sum += _mm256_extract_epi32(result, 0);
```

Can anyone point me to a possible solution or explanation ?

Thanks !

Comment: If you actually want to compute the sum of a larger array, you should first calculate 8 sums into a `__m256i` and only do a reduction at the end (to avoid latency, you can even accumulate into separate vectors which after the main loop you add together and then do a reduction as in the linked duplicate)

Comment: If you need this reduction for other types, here is a more generic question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction

Comment: Also, the reason why your method does not give correct results is that you only add up the elements of the lower half of `key_vec` -- you would need another reduction step (but see the linked question for how to actually do this)

Comment: `_mm512_reduce_add_epi32` is just a helper function, not a true intrinsic for a machine instruction.